# calculate values in multiple columns with error boolean

Tags: php, sql, boolean, sum

I am trying to calculate how many wins/ loses and how many games played.

I have a database named weeks and in there i store quite a few columns but now needing to calculate the total number of wins and loses for all weeks i have searched around and found [this page](http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/multiplying-column-values.html) which shows a nice example on how to use SUM.

My table is named weeks and it looks like this

```
id | fs1 | fs2 | fs3 | => fs12
```

I have been inserting rows for each week so for example

```
id | fs1 | fs2 | fs3 | => fs12
1     0     1     0        1           =2 wins
2     0     1     1        1           =3 wins
```

So using the code from the website i linked to above; this is my code i have at present but its not working.

```
 <?
//set connection variables
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "pool"; //database name

//connect to mysql server
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

//check if any connection error was encountered
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
    exit;
}
 $getTotalPoints = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(fs1 + fs2 + fs3 + fs4 + fs5 + fs6 + fs7 + fs8 + fs9 + fs10 + fs11 + fs12) wins FROM weeks");     
    $TotalPoints = mysql_fetch_array($getTotalPoints);
    echo $TotalPoints['wins'];
?>
```

This code gives me the following error `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 6`

Which is `$TotalPoints = mysql_fetch_array($getTotalPoints);`

When i do the query direct to the database i get the following messages

```
This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0012 sec)


wins
59
```

Comment: firstly, test your query, you query might have error **OR** there might be something wrong with your `'db_connect.php'`

Comment: i have checked db_connect and ran the query on the database directly and it comes up with the answer ill show you on my question what happens when i do do it direct.

Comment: so? the problem is at your `'db_connect.php'`, there must be `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` methods. are there those methods exist?

Comment: ill update my question to include the db_connect

Comment: ah! you are using `mysqli` for connection! so you can't use `mysql_query`

Comment: what would be the updated code for this then? man you guys must hate noobs! :)

Comment: just simply change `mysql_` to `mysqli_`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46115/discussion-between-tun-zarni-kyaw-and-rick-nash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created `mysqli` object for database connection, so you have to use `mysqli_query` method which need at least 2 parameters.

```
$getTotalPoints = mysqli_query($mysqli, 
"SELECT SUM(fs1 + fs2 + fs3 + fs4 + fs5 + fs6 + 
fs7 + fs8 + fs9 + fs10 + fs11 + fs12) wins FROM weeks");
```

Also, for the `mysql_fetch_array()` method you have to use `mysqli_` one

```
$TotalPoints = mysqli_fetch_array($getTotalPoints);
```